# Add boosting to specific document types in Umbraco using lucene

Tags: c#, search, lucene, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to boost specific Umbraco document types, but when viewing the score using Luke the Score 0.0035.

I'm using Lucene.net version 2.9.4.1.

[image]

I'm trying to add the boost by using the `DocumentWriting` event, my code is below, it does get called and i'm able to step through and make sure the correct boost line is reached:

```
using System;
using Examine;
using Examine.LuceneEngine;
using Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers;
using Spurs.Site.Models.Enums;
using Umbraco.Core;

namespace Spurs.Site.Infrastructure
{
    public class UmbracoEvents : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        public UmbracoEvents()
        {
            var indexer = (LuceneIndexer)ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection["ExternalIndexer"];

            indexer.DocumentWriting += Indexer_DocumentWriting;
        }

        private void Indexer_DocumentWriting(object sender, DocumentWritingEventArgs e)
        {
            string nodeTypeAlias;
            var hasNodeTypeAlias = e.Fields.TryGetValue("nodeTypeAlias", out nodeTypeAlias);

            if (!hasNodeTypeAlias)
                return;

            DocumentTypeAlias documentType = (DocumentTypeAlias)Enum.Parse(typeof(DocumentTypeAlias), nodeTypeAlias, true);

            switch (documentType)
            {
                case DocumentTypeAlias.playerPage:
                    e.Document.SetBoost(1000f);
                    break;
                case DocumentTypeAlias.fixturePage:
                    e.Document.SetBoost(500f);
                    break;
                default:
                    e.Document.SetBoost(1f);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I must be missing something, it's as if the `e.Document.SetBoost` isn't saved.

Comment: why do you boost while indexing time? i would suggest boosting while searching. this is how i usually do with plain lucene

Comment: you're using Lucene 3.5?